# Repaint a swing component while a thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a thread that I start when I press the start button. What I want to do is repaint the labels so they contain the information that my thread makes changes to. The only problem I am facing is that the jLabels repaint only after the thread is done running. Can someone give me any sugestions on how I can make it repaint while the thread is runnong? Thanks.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Store m = new Store(); //Store extends Thread
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    ....
    //I get the simulation time of the store from a textbox
    //the thread runs for this number of seconds
    //when it is done, the store is closed(the open variable is set to false)
    ....

    m.start();

    while (m.isOpen()) {
        queue0.setText(String.valueOf(m.clientiCasai(0)));
        //here I will have more queues
        ....
        noOfClients.repaint(); //this is the label that should show the number of clients in queue 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't run that while loop on the EDT but let your thread trigger the repaint events, which should already happen if the thread calls `noOfClients.setText(whatever)`.

Comment: Don't block the Swing thread. Repainting is called only after your action method done. `repaint()` performes no repainting, but only informs swing that the component must be repainted later. For more info read about [Concurency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Wrap in the setText() in SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()

Answer (score 1):

Your *startActionPerformed()* method should not run on EventDispatchThread (EDT) which is the Thread that shall be used for all Swing Modification operations. If you block the EDT your UI will not repaint, it will *freeze*.

Your *noOfClients.repaint()* call should be done on EDT, but also your call setting the new value to *queue0* label should be on EDT.

For simplification. If you your *queue0.setText()* call on EDT, the repainting will be done for you, so you can remove it.

This can be achieved by calling:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            queue0.setText("<text>");
        }
    });
```

To solve your problem you could either pass a reference to the instance holding the method *startActionPerformed()* to your Store and call it from there when needed or you could start another Thread that monitors the Store progress and propagates it to the Swing EDT.

Comment: `m.start();` is called from `startActionPerformed`. In other words, he starts the thread in `startActionPerformed`, so `startActionPerformed` runs in the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the actual painting is also done during the EDT's event loop; your `while()` loop is basically preventing the EDT from proceeding. 
One possible workaround would be to have an extra thread that would take care of updating the label.